# Prestashop 1.6.0.5 how to disable wishlist feature?

Tags: prestashop

Theme: pos_optima_digital.
I haven't found wishlist in modules. No special wishlist module installed, no such feature in theme.
Where can I turn this feature off?

Comment: as this is a premium theme, you can asked the theme developer to provide you the module. By default prestashop have this module. you  need to install that from prestashop back office.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

login to back-end and go to modules > wishlist block and click disable

Answer (score 0):

To "fix it", I searched for `blockwishlist` in all project, and comment out all links and references. Then run a "*Clear Cache*".